# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed flutter_youtube

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, flutter

I am trying to build my project using "flutter build apk" and I encountered the following error:

In my project, I am using flutter_youtube plugin:  flutter_youtube: ^1.1.4

I am not sure what this error means and how do I fix it.

> > FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':flutter_youtube:verifyReleaseResources'.
>
>   > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   >     linking failed   Output: 
>   >     C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerR adius not found.
>   >     C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11:
>   >     error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius no t found.
>   >     C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:964:
>   >     error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not fo und.
>   >     C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:965:
>   >     error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.   error: failed
>   >     linking references.
>
>   Command:
>     C:\Users\demo.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\6c5c55067bc3e37332d1bee0d534dc21\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>     link -I\
>           C:\Users\demo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\aapt_friendly_merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\aapt\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           C:\Users\demo\AppData\Local\Temp\aapt-2465429262595787253-out\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_fade_in.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_fade_out.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_popup_enter.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_popup_exit.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_slide_in_bottom.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_slide_in_top.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_slide_out_bottom.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_slide_out_top.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_tooltip_enter.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\anim_abc_tooltip_exit.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v21_abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v23_abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v23_abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v23_abc_color_highlight_material.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v23_abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v23_abc_tint_default.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v23_abc_tint_edittext.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v23_abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml.flat\
>           -R\
>           C:\Users\demo\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_new\build\flutter_youtube\intermediates\res\compiled\release\color-v23_abc_tint_spinner.xml.flat\

Here's my app gradle:

```
  def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion  '28'

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    /*configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'


    }*/
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    api "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
    api "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"
    api 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    api 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my pubspec.yaml:

```
    name: demo
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 0.9.0+1 # add dependency for Firebase Core
  share:
      git:
       url: https://github.com/d-silveira/flutter-share.git
  file_picker: ^1.1.1
  carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
  font_awesome_flutter: 8.2.0
  path_provider: ^0.4.0
  flutter_youtube: ^1.1.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.0
  firebase_core: ^0.3.0
  cached_network_image: ^0.5.1
  clippy_flutter: 1.0.0
  url_launcher: 5.0.1
  material_design_icons_flutter: 3.1.3493

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  english_words: ^3.1.5
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: 0.7.0

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: MyFlutterApp
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf
    - family: Lato
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Lato-LightItalic.ttf
    - family: LatoSemiBoldItalic
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Lato-SemiBoldItalic.ttf

  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 6):

Open your project in **Android studio**.
On the left go to every dependency project you have added, open build.gradle file. Every 'compileSdkVersion' should be 28.
This solved the problem for me!

---

If you don't use Android studio, and you don't know exactly what dependency's you have in your project, you can go to the location on your computer where Flutter stores all the libs.
(on my Mac that is `/Users/my_user/Tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`).
Then do a bulk search and replace something like `compileSdkVersion 27` replaced with `compileSdkVersion 28`.

Answer (score 0):

In the`./android/app/build.gradle` update `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 28. The resources referenced either by your project of one of your libraries were only added in API 28, so you cannot continue using version 27 anymore.